# Find dSYM Files locally

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I cannot seem to locate my .dSYM files and wanted to ask for some ideas to troubleshoot. I'm using FirebaseCrashlytics, and it is asking for a few UUID dSYM files.

In the past, I remember all you would do is go to your archive, show package contents, and inside the dSYM folder would be a ton of .dSYM files with UUIDs such as 619DB60E-DF83-316B-B3CB-6F3309B67218 etc

Now, when I do this, all I see is the following directory structure when I show package contents for my dSYM:

```
Contents
...Info.plist
...Resources <folder>
......DWARF <folder>
.........MyAppName
```

Where did all the files with the GUIDs go?
I checked in xcode and I have DWARF with dSYM FILE for my "Debug Information Format" variable settings.

Any other things to think about or look at? Any other details I can share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` and `DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME` variables in Xcode. The actual location will depend on your system (your mac, a CI pipeline, etc).

If you're looking to write a script to automatically locate them, you can use these variables. For example, to upload them automatically on build to Crashlytics, create a script like this below. Note - we're doing it via the Fabric pod and adjust the path to `GoogleService-Info.plist` to fit your file structure.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
$PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp $SRCROOT/App/Config/$TARGET_NAME/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

You'd want to run this on your production target near or at the end of your build scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I found that in my output of all variables this is set to no: DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT   and I feel like that is the problem. Any ideas where to set it?